# Best interface to read voltage signal on PC?

Tags: signal

I have a device that generates a 6.2 vdc pulse (from 0 vdc) periodically and would like to store the time between pulses with microsecond resolution. I don't care what the length of the signal is, just need to record the time when the signal goes high. Is there an OTS interface I can use for this, or can someone suggest a good approach for capturing this data, Arduino etc? TIA.

Comment: So a timer from leading edge to leading edge?

Comment: Yes, so if pulses occur at t0, t1, t2, ... I'm interested in saving data t1-t0, t2-t1, ... Seems like something like an ADC might work, but it's been a few years since I've built something like this so not sure what a good approach would be, esp. now that PCs don't typically have serial ports any longer.

Comment: An ADC would be overkill; a Schmitt trigger would be enough. And interfacing to a PC is easy these days, with all the bidirectional USB-to-parallel ICs out there.

Comment: OK so basically look for a USB to parallel chip as the main interface component to the PC. Thank you.

Comment: @Jim, in my opinion you'd need a microcontroller or something other that a straight USB to parallel chip. You won't get microsecond resolution with those because of delays in the USB stack.

Answer (score 3):

One problem with trying to measure the pulses with microsecond accuracy directly over USB is that there will be delays in the USB stack and no popular desktop operating systems are real-time. Apart from latency the delays won't be consistent so you'll introduce jitter into the measurements as well.

A better approach would be a microcontroller that can record the timestamps internally and then send those timestamps over the USB port. There are a few ways to do that and it could be done with an 8 bit micro and some clever programming, but it is complicated by the fact that most only have 16-bit timers and clock rates around 20MHz or so. For a one-off project I'd recommend looking at something 32-bit like an ARM.

I haven't used one myself but the [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue) is one example and the Arduino boards in general tend to have a lot of example code and tutorials floating around. The library contains a [micros()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Micros) function that returns the number of microseconds the program has been running so you could record the delta between values (although be aware it wraps around). To detect the edge you could use the [attachInterrupt()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt) function to call an interrupt service routine on the rising edge of the signal.

On the interfacing side you could connect to any of the I/O pins listed as being an external interrupt. The board runs at 3.3V so it's important not to apply a voltage higher than that to avoid damage. In your case a pair of 10K resistors configured as a voltage divider would give 3.1V which is enough to be read as a high and gives you some safety margin for tolerances.

Comment: I like that approach Peter and it gives me an excuse to try some microcontroller programming. Thank you.